# How to use AND logic operator using MongoDB\Driver\Manager class in PHP Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to login a user if user name and password exist in the database. I have done so far is

```
<?php
    try {       
        $name  = 'john';
        $password = 12345;

        $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        $filter = [ 'name' => $name ]; 
        $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);     

        $res = $manager->executeQuery("DBName.Col", $query);

        $data = current($res->toArray());
        if (!empty($data)) {   

        } else {
            echo 0;
        }   
    } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {

        $filename = basename(__FILE__);     
        echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n"; 
        echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";
        echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
        echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";    
    }
?>
```

The line successfully filters the data if exists in the database `$filter = [ 'name' => $name ];` But how can I confirm the password too? Will it not be odd if I get the password using username and then compare the passwords?

Comment: `$filter = [ 'name' => $name, 'password' => $password ]; ` if you keep it as plain text.

Comment: @AlexBlex Plain text? for return?

Comment: For password. Usually passwords are being kept encrypted.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks God bless you.